# How to check span in for loop according to number of variable jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5.5

I want to number of star rating marked according to user rating given. For instance:- I 4 rating then 4 star should be coloured and the last star not to be coloured. I am using `<span>` tag for this. Here is my code:-

```
for(i=0; i<res_review.length; i++)
{
  var src = res_review[i];
  var rating = '<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span><span class="fa fa-star"></span><span class="fa fa-star"></span>';
}
```

In the above code, the 'rating' variable contains the 3 star rating because in the code 'checked' class is written statically. What my requirement is the 'res_review.length' in for loop contains 4 star rating. So i want that 4 span tags to contain 'checked' class dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
for(i=0; i<res_review.length; i++)
{
    var src = res_review[i];
    var rating = '';
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){ // out of five star
      if(i < src ){
        rating += '<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>';
      }else{
        rating += '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>'
      }
    }
}
```

```js
var src = 3;
var rating = '';
for(i=0; i<5; i++){ // out of five star
  if(i < src ){
    rating += '<span class="fa fa-star checked">*</span>';
  }else{
    rating += '<span class="fa fa-star">*</span>'
  }
}
document.querySelector("#stars").innerHTML = rating;
```

```css
.checked{
   color:red;
}
.fa-star{
   font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="stars">
</div>
```

Comment: @TS.developer : accept an answer which solved. Alos upvote which helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner loop to build the repeated `span` elements in the HTML. If index of the current star is less than the review then show the highlighted star, otherwise only an outline of it. Try this:

```js
var $reviews = $('#reviews');
[1, 4, 3, 2, 5].forEach(function(review) {
  var stars = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var className = i <= review - 1 ? 'fa-star' : 'fa-star-o';
    stars.push(`<span class="fa ${className}"></span>`);
  }
  $('<div />').appendTo($reviews).html(stars.join(''));
});
```

```css
.fa-star { color: gold; }
.fa-star-o { color: #EEE; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div id="reviews"></div>
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel for loop in blade file and display star like this

```
@for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
    @if($i<=$rating)
        <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
    @else
        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    @endif
@endfor
```

In this example, I get 5 is total rating star and $rating is given rating 
For jquery, you can do like this

```
var html = "";
for(var i=1;i<=5;i++){
    if(i <= rating){
        html.='<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>';
    }else{
        html.='<span class="fa fa-star"></span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i am doing it through jquery. But this is also useful.

Comment: I have updated my answer for jquery if it's useful for you than mark right so other user easily use this